# What's better for view as or mxml on mobile

Tags: apache-flex

As the title says what's better for writing views on mobile application : AS or MXML, in performance and visual?

I've tested the two ways and I found out that sometimes the mxml works better than AS

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with @Apocalyptic0n3: HTML and JS are 2 completely different languages, whereas MXML is just a declarative way to write AS. MXML code is compiled to AS first and the generated AS is then compiled to ABC bytecode, just like regular AS.

This means that as long as you use the Flex component hierarchy for writing your components in AS there will be **hardly any performance difference**. And anything you can write in MXML can be written in AS. Some of the generated code may be useless to your specific use case, so there's some optimization that could be done there, but it would hardly be noteicable in most cases. (If you write pure AS components outside the Flex framework, that's a whole other story of course)

The main difference is the speed at which you write your code, because you're going to put **a lot more time** into writing a component in AS as opposed to MXML.

In MXML you would also naturally use **data bindings**, whereas in a component written in AS you would usually set properties by overriding the `commitProperties()` method. There is a significant performance difference to be made here, but it doesn't mean you can't use bindings in AS, or you can't override `commitProperties` in an MXML-based component.

Answer (score -1):

MXML is far superior than AS3 in terms of GUI layouts. It's faster to write and far, far more flexible (and you can still use AS3 to boot), and generally faster in overall speed, especially since you do not need to bind resize listeners. MXML and AS3 are meant to be used together, just as HTML and JS are.

Comment: -1 for a few reasons.  MXML is not more flexible than ActionScript.  I'd say you can do lots more in ActionScript than you can in MXML.  Since MXML is translated into ActionScript by the Flex compiler; MXML is not faster performing.  In some cases, MXML can be slower performing because of things that the Flex compiler does during this translation.  The use of MXML or ActionScript has absolutely nothing to do with resizing components.  I'm not even sure what you mean by "Bind resize listeners".  I do agree that MXML is superior for GUI layouts, is faster to write, and designed to be used w/ AS3

Comment: If you want to have a resizable/flexible interface with AS3, you need to run all the sizing and positioning through a stage resize function. With MXML, it sizes automatically. Granted, I am sure that is done the exact same way in the compiler, but it is FAR easier to write. In terms of GUI flexibility, I don't think AS3 even comes close, though. Sure, you can do everything in Flex with AS3, but the difficulty involved to do something as simple as a Spark Button is hardly worth it. I will agree that I was wrong on speed, however. You brought up a good point there.

Comment: `you need to run all the sizing and positioning through a stage resize function` > not true. Perhaps you missed [percentWidth](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#percentWidth) and [percentHeight](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#percentHeight)

Comment: In addition to @RIAStar's comment: "With MXML, it sizes automatically" That is not true. Flex components size automatically because a measure method was implemented as part of the Flex Component Lifecycle.  measure() calculates values for measuredHeight, measuredWidth, measuredMinHeight & measuredMinWidth properties.  Flex layout containers use those values to size a compoment if no explicit size is provided. Such code has nothing to do w/ MXML.  In terms of GUI Flexibility; I think you're confusing flexibility w/ ease of use. MXML is easier to write than AS3; but AS3 provides more options